# Networkx not working at all - weird errors for the most basic operations

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to do some work with the networkx package in python and am stuck at the most basic level. I cannot even get the simplest code snippets to work in my environment.

For example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from([2, 3])
G.add_nodes_from(range(4, 7))

G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 1)
G.add_edges_from([(2,3), (3,6), (4,6), (5,6)])

list(G.nodes)
```

This throws the following error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-280-90765acb4d1b> in <module>()
>       9 G.add_edges_from([(2,3), (3,6), (4,6), (5,6)])
>      10 
> ---> 11 list(G.nodes)
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tracx\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py in
> nodes(self)
>     717 
>     718         """
> --> 719         nodes = NodeView(self)
>     720         # Lazy View creation: overload the (class) property on the instance
>     721         # Then future G.nodes use the existing View
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tracx\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py
> in __init__(self, graph)
>     166 
>     167     def __init__(self, graph):
> --> 168         self._nodes = graph._node
>     169 
>     170     # Mapping methods
> 
> TypeError: descriptor '_nodes' for 'NodeView' objects doesn't apply to
> 'NodeView' object
```

I've got 2.1 installed and run it from Jupyter notebook with python 3.5.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Verify your version of Networkx, `nx.__version__`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your last line.
If you use an old networkx version (say 1.11),  `G.nodes` should be replaced with `G.nodes()`.
In version 2.1 you can also use `G.nodes` as you do.